# How to include platform specific resources with Electron Builder?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am developing an Electron application that utilizes some executables in the background. Since I am building a multiplatform application, I want to package different executables for the target platforms. Currently, I am using "extraResources" to append the executables to my Electron project, but that makes my app weigh much more than necessary because all of the resources are bundled into the final destination.

Let's say I have a file structure like this:

```
resources
├── windows
│    └── file.exe
├── linux
│    └── file.tar
└── osx
     └── file.tar
```

How can I bundle platform-specific files/resources, so they would only be packaged to the corresponding platform's build output?